# initiliaze git from SRC folder

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea

Hello so I'm working on a Java project for a class, using Intellij. My teacher does not want an SRC folder or anything else that Intellij makes on the Github Repo. Would it be possible to initialize a git repository in the SRC? or would it create problems for Intelj

Comment: Hint: git does not care about `src` folder. Intellij is the one who uses the `src` folder as default for java projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possibilities to approach this problem:

- [Create the git-repository in a separate folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505467/can-i-store-the-git-folder-outside-the-files-i-want-tracked). Note though that this approach is a bit tricky to get right! There are actually two options for this:

  - `git --work-tree=<project-location>/src` to use git from a separate directory.
  - `git --git-dir=<rep-location>` to use the specified location for the repository. This will require you to use `--git-dir` every time.
- Initialize the repository inside the src-folder. This one for sure is ugly, but IntelliJ shouldn't care at all about any non-java files during compilation and if it still complains you could even [exclude the directory from being compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291986/intellij-exclude-file-from-being-compiled)
- [Use a `.gitignore`-file to exclude files from VCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050487/git-creating-a-gitignore-file). This would leave the src-folder in the repository, but apart from that you can exclude any file you feel like from being versioned. (See the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and [@CrazyCoders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46229620/4668606) answer for more details on this)
- Do something funny with symlinks. I.e. create the repository somewhere else, place a symlink in the src-folder and use the repository via the symlink.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839). You can exclude IntelliJ IDEA project files (`.idea` directory and `.iml` files from the version control).

Here is the sample [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore) for IntelliJ IDEA projects that you can adjust for your needs.